# How to call a fallback function in remix

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x, remix-tests

I have the below code in remix. I remember the remix had the "fallback" button to check the fallback method. I am back after long time. I do not find the "fallback" button. I wonder how to call and test the fallback method using Remix.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;


contract FuncConcert {
uint constant price = .1 ether;
address public owner;
uint public tickets;
mapping (address => uint ) public purchasers;

constructor (uint t) public payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
    tickets = t;
}

event Received(address sender, uint value);   // declaring event

receive() external payable {
    emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

// ------------------- FallBack Function --------------------------
fallback () external payable    {
    buyTickets(1);
}
// ------------------- FallBack Function -------------------------- 

function buyTickets(uint reqTkts) public payable {  
    
    require (msg.value == (reqTkts * price) && reqTkts <= tickets);
    
    purchasers[msg.sender] += reqTkts;
    tickets-= reqTkts;
    if (tickets ==0 ) {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    }
}

function buyTickets(uint reqTkts,uint freeTickets) public payable { 
    require (msg.value == (reqTkts * price) && (reqTkts+freeTickets) <= tickets);
    
    purchasers[msg.sender] += (freeTickets+reqTkts);
    tickets-= (freeTickets+reqTkts);
    
    if (tickets ==0 ) {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    }
}

function website() public pure returns (string memory){ 
    return "www.FuncConcert.com"; 
}


// this is how we add a modifier to the function 
// there can be zero of more number of modifiers
function kill() public onlyCreator {  
    selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
}

modifier onlyCreator() {
    // if a condition is not met then throw an exception 
     require (msg.sender == owner); 
    // or else just continue executing the function
    _;
}
```

}

Comment: Probably on the left side down under low level interaction

Comment: However I don’t remember if a fallback function can do what u want to do,  from what I remember it has a gas limit and can’t change the state or create a storage

Comment: it is not on the left side. I checked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I deploy the contract I get it on the left side down. it called ‘low level interaction’ and depends on the input there the receiver or fallback function is called. My contract don’t have them therefore i get the red hint. And as I said your fallback function will not work because of the gas limit of that function, u need to find another way to do that.

Clicking on Transact without Data will call the receive function, and if you give any or dummy data (e.g. "0x001122") it will call the fallback function

[image]

Comment: Can you please let me know what sample data I can give in "CALLDATA" so that the Fallback is called ?

Comment: @iappmaker if you call it empty then it will call the "receiver" function.. if you call it with any data it will call the "fallback" function. try "0x001122" as input and then click on Transact